# Scala pattern matching with grep

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am learning scala from Odersky's book
Programming in Scala: A Comprehensive Step-by-Step Guide

This code

```
object n3 {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {

val filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles 
for (file <- filesHere if file.getName.endsWith(".scala"))
  println(file)
    }
}
```

gives a list of all .scala file in my folder

```
./p6.scala
./m9.scala
./n1.scala
./m6.scala
./n4.scala
./m3.scala
./p5.scala
./m2.scala
./p9.scala
./d7.scala
./p7.scala
./m7.scala
./d5.scala
./d14.scala
./r12.scala
./test.scala
./m1.scala
./d12.scala
./n3.scala
./d3.scala
./m5.scala
./echoargs.scala
./m8.scala
./d8.scala
./d4.scala
./r11.scala
./d13.scala
./p2.scala
./p3.scala
./d2.scala
./n2.scala
./p1.scala
./d6.scala
./p8.scala
./p4.scala
./Rational.scala
./m4.scala
./d1.scala
./r13.scala
./d11.scala
```

When I try next example

```
object n4 {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {

val filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles

def fileLines (file: java.io.File)=
  scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines().toList

def grep(pattern: String)=
  for(
  file <- filesHere
  if file.getName.endsWith(".scala");
  line <- fileLines(file)
  if line.trim.matches(pattern)
  ) println(file +" :"+ line.trim)

grep(".*m9.*")
  }
}
```

I got

```
milenko@milenko-desktop:~$ scala n4
./n4.scala :grep(".*m9.*")
```

It seems that I do not understand what `trim.match` is supposed to do.I thought that it should list only ./m9.scala.What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.trim` removes the starting and ending whitespaces and returns another `String`

The resulting `String` is compared with the provided regex through the `.matches` method

Answer (score 3):

The code is checking file *contents*, not file *names*: `trim.matches` is called on `line`.

File `n4.scala` contains the line `grep(".*m9.*")` (it's the second to last one), which matches the pattern `.*m9.*` (any line which contains `m9` does). If you look into `m9.scala`, it likely doesn't contain `m9` anywhere.